# How to convert iso-8601 duration to seconds using moment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, iso

I have an iso-8601 duration which is as follows:

```
PT15M51S
```

I want to convert the duration into *seconds* so that I can store it in the db and order by duration etc.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var duration = 'PT15M51S';
var x = moment(duration, moment.ISO_8601);
console.log(x.seconds());
```

Which results in `NaN`.

Comment: momentjs is huge. If you are only converting the value, use this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso8601-duration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) function. Also, to get the total value in seconds, use [`asSeconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/) instead of `seconds()`.

In your case:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var duration = 'PT15M51S';
var x = moment.duration(duration, moment.ISO_8601);
console.log(x.asSeconds()); // => 951
```

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll check this out now.

Comment: error TS2345: Argument of type 'MomentBuiltinFormat' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DurationConstructor'.
  Type 'MomentBuiltinFormat' is not assignable to type '"Q"'.